# logical not of substringof() in 2013 REST API

Tags: 2013, rest

I'd like to filter a rest request and get the opposite of:

```
filter=substringof('foo', Title)
```

I've tried with a leading "not" and also ending with "eq false" but those it seems are not valid queries.  I guess what I'm really lacking is a complete documentation of the filter regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like there is a bug with `substringof` operator in REST/OData web service implementation.

### Symptoms

When applying `substringof` operator to a list items using the following syntax:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts')/items?$filter=substringof('John', Title) eq false
```

an error occurs:

```
<m:error 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The query is not valid.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

### Workaround

You could target the `listdata.svc` where substringof operator could be applied successfully.

Example:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Contacts?$filter=substringof('Jane',LastName) eq false
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. It seems this bug has not been fixed my Microsoft yet. But  the alternative you provided work perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The figure below shows the supported OData query options and how to specify supported filters
[image]

You can find the full documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

The following Url is working fine at my end:

```
_api/web/Lists?$filter=substringof('Documents',Title) eq false
```

Comment: this solution not work for me

Comment: This syntax worked for me, using SharePoint 2016 Server with the December 2018 CU.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append eq true/false as in this working filter for SharePoint o365:

```
?$filter=substringof('Johnston', Title) eq true &$select=Id,Title,Email
```

the **eq true** is **outside** the substringof parenthesis.