# Searching through REST API and CAML with Paging

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, spservices

I have requirement to filter two fields with substring but I found out that substring is not working in REST API it have some kind of bug. So below question stackexchange.com suggested to use listdata.svc

[logical not of substringof() in 2013 REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101266/logical-not-of-substringof-in-2013-rest-api/101303)

But I cannot use two fields at the same time with listdata.svc. So I decided to use CAML Query with spservices jquery but there paging is not working.

Below is my code

```
var news = ''
    $().SPServices({
      operation: 'GetListItems',
      async: false,
      webURL: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,
      listName: 'News',
      CAMLQuery: `<Query>
                    <Where>
                        <And>
                          <Or>
                              <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>KFH</Value>
                              </Contains>
                              <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name='Detail' />
                                <Value Type='Note'>KFH</Value>
                              </Contains>
                          </Or>
                          <Eq>
                              <FieldRef Name='Active' />
                              <Value Type='Choice'>Yes</Value>
                          </Eq>
                        </And>
                    </Where>
                    <OrderBy>
                      <FieldRef Name='PublishDate' Ascending='False' />
                    </OrderBy>
                  </Query>`,
      CAMLViewFields: `<ViewFields>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <FieldRef Name='Detail' />
                        <FieldRef Name='PublishDate' />
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                        <FieldRef Name='Attachments' />
                      </ViewFields>`,
      CAMLRowLimit: 6,
      CAMLQueryOptions:
        "<QueryOptions><Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext='" +
        newpos +
        "'><QueryOptions>",
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        pos = $(xData.responseXML)
          .find("[nodeName='rs:data']")
          .attr('ListItemCollectionPositionNext')
        $(xData.responseXML)
          .SPFilterNode('z:row')
          .each(function() {
            news = 'HTML CODE'
            $('#news').append(news)
          })
      },
    })
```

I don't know but CAMLQueryOptions never works and never works paging. Please help  for forward paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following script:

*Note: Change the listname, pagesize and other information based on your requirement.*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var context, 
    web, 
    spItems, 
    position, 
    nextPagingInfo, 
    previousPagingInfo, 
    listName = 'cl02', 
    pageIndex = 1, // default page index value 
    pageSize = 2, // default page size value 
    list, 
    camlQuery, 
    sortColumn = 'PublishDate'; // this is sort column, you can add more than one column, but you should add it also to CAML Query & managePagerControl function

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model  
$(document).ready(function () { 
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 
        camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 

        $("#btnNext").click(function () { 
            pageIndex = pageIndex + 1; 
            if (nextPagingInfo) { 
                position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
                position.set_pagingInfo(nextPagingInfo); 
            } 
            else { 
                position = null; 
            } 

            GetListItems(); 
        }); 

        $("#btnBack").click(function () { 
            pageIndex = pageIndex - 1; 
            position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
            position.set_pagingInfo(previousPagingInfo); 
            GetListItems(); 
        }); 

        GetListItems(); 
    });
}); 

function GetListItems() { 
    //Set the next or back list items collection position 
    //First time the position will be null 
    camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position); 

    // Create a CAML view that retrieves all contacts items  with assigne RowLimit value to the query 
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" + 
                                "<ViewFields>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='Detail'/>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='PublishDate'/>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='ID' />"+
                                       "<FieldRef Name='Attachments' />"+
                                  "</ViewFields>" + 
                               "<Query>" + 
                                "<Where>" +
                                    "<And>" +
                                      "<Or>" +
                                          "<Contains>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                            "<Value Type='Text'>KFH</Value>" +
                                          "</Contains>" +
                                          "<Contains>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='Detail' />" +
                                            "<Value Type='Note'>KFH</Value>" +
                                          "</Contains>" +
                                      "</Or>" +
                                      "<Eq>" +
                                          "<FieldRef Name='Active' />" +
                                          "<Value Type='Choice'>Yes</Value>" +
                                      "</Eq>" +
                                    "</And>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                    "<OrderBy>"+
                                    "<FieldRef Name='"+sortColumn+"' Ascending='False' />"+
                                    "</OrderBy>"+
                               "</Query>" + 
                               "<RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>"); 

    spItems = list.getItems(camlQuery); 

    context.load(spItems); 
    context.executeQueryAsync( 
            Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, onFail) 
        ); 
} 

// This function is executed if the above OM call is successful 
// This function render the returns items to html table 
function onSuccess() { 

    var listEnumerator = spItems.getEnumerator(); 
    var items = []; 
    var item; 

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) { 
        item = listEnumerator.get_current(); 
        items.push("<td>" + item.get_item('Title') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('Detail') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('PublishDate') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('ID') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('Attachments') + "</td>"); 
    } 

    var content = "<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Detail</th><th>PublishDate</th><th>ID</th><th>Attachments</th></tr><tr>" 
                + items.join("</tr><tr>") + "</tr></table>"; 
    $('#content').html(content); 

    managePagerControl(); 
} 

function onFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function managePagerControl() { 

    if (spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition()) { 
        nextPagingInfo = spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition().get_pagingInfo(); 
    } else { 
        nextPagingInfo = null; 
    } 

    $("#pageInfo").html((((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize) + 1) + " - " + ((pageIndex * pageSize) - (pageSize - spItems.get_count()))); 

    previousPagingInfo = "PagedPrev=TRUE&Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + spItems.itemAt(0).get_item('ID') + "&p_" + sortColumn + "=" + encodeURIComponent(spItems.itemAt(0).get_item(sortColumn).toISOString()); 

    if (pageIndex <= 1) { 
        $("#btnBack").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#btnBack").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 

    if (nextPagingInfo) { 
        $("#btnNext").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#btnNext").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 

}
</script>
<div id ="content"></div>
<div><input type="button"id="btnBack" value="Back"/><span id="pageInfo"></span><input type="button"id="btnNext" value="Next"/></div>
```

Testing results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx

Code example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92